# Incorrect ordering on query with group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following query:

```
SELECT sensor.id as `sensor_id`,
       sensor_reading.id as `reading_id`,
       sensor_reading.reading as `reading`,
       from_unixtime(sensor_reading.reading_timestamp) as `reading_timestamp`,
       sensor_reading.lower_threshold as `lower_threshold`,
       sensor_reading.upper_threshold as `upper_threshold`,
       sensor_type.units as `unit`
FROM sensor
LEFT JOIN sensor_reading ON sensor_reading.sensor_id = sensor.id
LEFT JOIN sensor_type ON sensor.sensor_type_id = sensor_type.id
WHERE sensor.company_id = 1
GROUP BY sensor_reading.sensor_id
ORDER BY sensor_reading.reading_timestamp DESC
```

There are three tables in play here. A **sensor_type** table, which is just used for a single display field (units), a **sensor** table, which contains information on a sensor, and a **sensor_reading** table, which contains the individual readings for a sensor. There are multiple readings which apply to a single sensor, and so each entry in the sensor_reading table has a *sensor_id* which is linked to the *ID* field in the sensor table with a foreign key constraint.

In theory, this query should return the most recent sensor_reading for EACH unique sensor. Instead, it's returning the first reading for each sensor instead. I've seen a few posts on here with similar issues, but haven't been able to resolve this using any of their answers. Ideally, the query needs to be as efficient as possible, as this table has several thousand readings (and continues to grow).

Does anyone know how I might change this query to return the most recent reading? If I remove the **GROUP BY** clause, it returns the right order, but I then have to sift through the data to get the most recent for each sensor.

Ideally, I don't want to run sub-queries as this slows things down a lot, and speed is a big factor here.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see aggregate function like count or max then why you use group by ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In theory, this query should return the most recent sensor_reading for EACH unique sensor.

This is a fairly common misconception with the [MySQL Group by extension](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html), that allows you to select columns with no aggregation that are not contained in the group by clause. What the documentation states is:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause

So since you are grouping by `sensor_reading.sensor_id`, MySQL will chose **any** row from `sensor_reading` for each `sensor_id`, then **after** choosing one row for each `sensor_id` it will then apply the ordering to the rows that are chosen.

Since you only want the latest row for each sensor, the general approach would be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sensor_reading AS sr
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    sensor_reading AS sr2
            WHERE   sr2.sensor_id = sr.sensor_id
            AND     sr2.reading_timestamp > sr.reading_timestamp
        );
```

However, [MySQL will optimise `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` better than `NOT EXISTS`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) so a MySQL specific solution would be:

```
SELECT  sr.*
FROM    sensor_reading AS sr
        LEFT JOIN sensor_reading AS sr2
            ON sr2.sensor_id = sr.sensor_id
            AND sr2.reading_timestamp > sr.reading_timestamp
WHERE   sr2.id IS NULL;
```

So incorporating this into your query, you would end up with:

```
SELECT sensor.id as `sensor_id`,
       sensor_reading.id as `reading_id`,
       sensor_reading.reading as `reading`,
       from_unixtime(sensor_reading.reading_timestamp) as `reading_timestamp`,
       sensor_reading.lower_threshold as `lower_threshold`,
       sensor_reading.upper_threshold as `upper_threshold`,
       sensor_type.units as `unit`
FROM    sensor
        LEFT JOIN sensor_reading 
            ON sensor_reading.sensor_id = sensor.id
        LEFT JOIN sensor_type 
            ON sensor.sensor_type_id = sensor_type.id
        LEFT JOIN sensor_reading AS sr2
            ON sr2.sensor_id = sensor_reading.sensor_id
            AND sr2.reading_timestamp > sensor_reading.reading_timestamp
WHERE sensor.company_id = 1
AND sr2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY sensor_reading.reading_timestamp DESC;
```

An alternative method for getting the maximum per group is to inner join back to the latest row, so something like:

```
SELECT  sr.*
FROM    sensor_reading AS sr
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  sensor_id, MAX(reading_timestamp) AS reading_timestamp
            FROM    sensor_reading
            GROUP BY sensor_id
        ) AS sr2
            ON sr2.sensor_id = sr.sensor_id
            AND sr2.reading_timestamp = sr.reading_timestamp;
```

You may find that this is more efficient than the other method, or you may not, YMMV. It basically depends on your data and indexes, and as you have said, subqueries can be an issue in MySQL due to the fact that the full result is matierialised initially.

Comment: OP says "In theory, this query". In some wrong theory somewhere, maybe... **+10.**  Quote for the day:  **In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is.** - Unknown

Comment: @GarethD, this works. Unfortunately it takes quite a while to run the query so I think I'm going to have to look at a different solution. Possibly looping through the sensor IDs and running individual queries for each sensor. At least that way I can do it in batches. Thanks again for the explanation though. Helps to know exactly *why* the GROUP BY clause isn't working. Much 'ppreciated sir!

Comment: You probably want to think about adding an index on sensor_reading  (sensor_id, reading_time) before thinking about loops